# WinMinimize and WinMaximize

Tags: windows-7, automation, autohotkey

In the docs, they have an example

```
^Down::WinMinimize, A
```

So I tried to create the following:

```
^m::WinMinimize
#^!m::WinMaximize
^m::WinMinimize, A
#^!m::WinMaximize, A
```

But it only works in notepad++ not in explorer or chrome etc. Where do I go wrong?

Please not that I seek to minimize only one (1) window at a time. Using #m minimizes all windows in a certain application.

Comment: You have the same set of keys assigned twice? ^m in lines 1 and 3, the other combination in lines 2 and 4. Do you have any #IfWinActive lines before those lines? You have to deactivate #IfWinActive if these mappings to work globally. Or they have to be before any #IfWinActive lines in the script.

Comment: No, it's not assigned twice, I only wanted to state that I tried both with and without appending ", A". I do not have #IfWinActive.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in an empty script...

```
#persistent
^m::WinMinimize, A
```